# Chrome extension - works locally, does not work when installed from the store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Chrome extension - works locally, does not work when installed from the store

Manifest

```
{
   "manifest_version": 3,
   "name": "Bracelet",
   "version": "0.5.0",
   "description": "Bracelet Extension",
   "icons": {
     "16": "icons/icon_16.png",
     "32": "icons/icon_32.png",
     "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
     "128": "icons/icon_128.png"
   },
   "background": {
     "service_worker": "background.js"
   },
   "action": {
     "default_title": "Bracelet",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "permissions": ["storage"],
   "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
       "run_at": "document_idle",
       "js": ["contentScript.js"]
     }
   ]
}
```

contentScript.js has the following function

```
const pageTitle = document.head.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(`Page title is: '${pageTitle}' - ${window.location.href}`);
```

Locally, everything works in the console, the page title is displayed, when installing from the store - it does not work.

What could be the problem?

Extension page if needed - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bracelet/gobafpojcifnmhfdeojfgpekckneciog

The full functionality of the extension is available only on the medical system page, but the log console can be tested on any page.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the posted code, i.e. it's insufficient to diagnose the problem. Note that you need to [re-inject content scripts explicitly](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.

Comment: That is, restarting the browser or making ctrl+f5 is not enough to correctly install the extension?

Comment: Reloading tabs or restarting the browser is enough and your extension works for me. The link I gave is for enabling the functionality immediately.